Excel VBA: Compile Error: Expected Sub, Function, or Property
I was writing a code to input data from another sheet into a table and got the error stated above, below are the code:
Sub data_input()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheets
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim last_row As Long
    
    Set ws = Sheets(Letters)
    Set table = ws.Tables(Tracker)
    
    last_row = table.Range("C" & table.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Application.CountA(table.Range("C" & last_row)) = 0 Then
        last_row 1
    
    
    table.Cells(last_row, 3).Value = Range("entity").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 4).Value = Range("letter_type").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 6).Value = Range("bu").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 8).Value = Range("date").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 9).Value = Range("project_name").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 10).Value = Range("enduser_name").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 11).Value = Range("partner_name").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 12).Value = Range("requestor_name").Value
    table.Cells(last_row, 13).Value = Range("details").Value

End Sub

and below is the error picture:
Error prompt:

Error highlight:

Would need some advice and help. Thanks
I am not sure what to try so would need some help on what can I try or fix in the code.
Edit: I missed the explanation on the last_row line, it is supposed to be last_row + 1, but somehow when I save it reverts back to that, any idea why that happens?

What do you expect from last_row 1?

Try If Application.CountA(table.Range("C" & last_row)) = 0 Then last_row = 1 and delete last_row 1...

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

It's a simple typo, it should be:
last_row = 1

(You have forgotten the equality sign for assigning the value 1 to last_row)
As a result, VBA thinks that last_row is some function which takes 1 as an input parameter for doing something, something like:
print "hello"

, where "hello" is the parameter, given to the print instruction, so that the program knows what to print.
